# Count children when parents and children in same table

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for a good way to count how many children a person has, given that each person has a mother and father attribute. My use case is a little unique in that a person can be either a mother or a father (strange biology).

Given a table like this:

Persons:

```
person_id   father_id    mother_id
123         321          324
321         324          555
456         321          324
```

Currently the only index is person_id and all IDs are integer types.

Desired outcome:

```
person_id     child_count
324           3
321           2
555           1
123           0
321           0
456           0
```

I have one potential solution:

```
SELECT parent.person_id, COUNT(child.person_id) AS child_count
FROM person AS parent
LEFT JOIN person AS child ON parent.person_id IN (child.father_id, child.mother_id)
GROUP BY parent.person_id
```

But it is extremely slow. I have over 1,000,000 people in my table and this query crashes when the limit is higher than about 1,000 or so. I'm looking for a way to do this using far less table scans, perhaps with windowing or a similar technique.

Additional Information from EXPLAIN (LIMIT set to 1,000 otherwise it runs forever):

```
"Limit  (cost=0.43..59655056.17 rows=1000 width=12) (actual time=2602.990..567136.183 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=15714 read=106549, temp read=7134255 written=7136"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..158992117664.04 rows=2665191 width=12) (actual time=2602.989..567135.552 rows=1000 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: parent.person_id"
"        Buffers: shared hit=15714 read=106549, temp read=7134255 written=7136"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..158992064366.44 rows=5329137 width=8) (actual time=2062.008..567130.915 rows=1484 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: ((parent.person_id = child.mother_id) OR (parent.person_id = child.father_id))"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2659776826"
"              Buffers: shared hit=15714 read=106549, temp read=7134255 written=7136"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using person_id_pkey on person parent  (cost=0.43..359957.14 rows=2665191 width=4) (actual time=0.114..11.580 rows=1001 loops=1)"
"                    Heap Fetches: 701"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=264 read=242"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..174748.86 rows=2665191 width=12) (actual time=0.003..288.154 rows=2657121 loops=1001)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=15450 read=106307, temp read=7134255 written=7136"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on person child  (cost=0.00..148408.91 rows=2665191 width=12) (actual time=0.029..987.744 rows=2657770 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=15450 read=106307"
"Planning Time: 0.110 ms"
"Execution Time: 567145.740 ms"
```

Comment: Can you share how the tables is defined, especially what indices you have created on it?

Comment: If your problem is a working but slow query, please include the query plan (from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`)

Comment: If you didn't care about zero counts, you could do a UNION of father_id and mother_id and count from that: SELECT pid as person_id, count(pid) as child_count FROM (SELECT mother_id as pid FROM person UNION ALL SELECT father_id as pid FROM person) GROUP BY pid. I suppose you'd have to do a separate query to find people without children.

Comment: Please describe in detail what you mean by "crashes". A million rows is not much, so it should be reasonably fast. Please also add `EXPLAIN` output for the query without `LIMIT` to the question.

Comment: @bergi I've included the Explain details, I had to limit it to 1,000 rows otherwise it runs for hours.

Comment: "*Currently the only index is person_id*" - you definitely should try adding indices on `father_id` and `mother_id` as well, that should speed up your query considerably. Alternatively, try the one that @bfris suggested - what query plan does that have?